# JavaFX StackOverflowError while using WebView in rich UI application

Tags: java, webview, javafx, stack-overflow

I run into problem while using WebView,when i load it it looks all colored flickering and after while straight into stackOverFlowError.

**Seems like a recursion to me.I dont think increasing stack size via -Xss (Already tried) will help here.
What are my options?**

**May this be caused by BIG SCENE GRAPH? I have fairly heavy Graphicly intensive UI 553 Nodes When main view is open, 266 Nodes when Browser page loaded.In separated FXML files and separated controllers.**

Error with GMaps(uses webView):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.<init>(BaseGraphics.java:89)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.<init>(BaseShaderGraphics.java:86)
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DGraphics.<init>(D3DGraphics.java:42)
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DGraphics.create(D3DGraphics.java:65)
    at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DRTTexture.createGraphics(D3DRTTexture.java:77)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.RTImage.getGraphics(RTImage.java:68)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)

...and so on
```

Error on another WebView (Vanilla no libs used):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.javafx.geom.transform.AffineBase.transform(AffineBase.java:1021)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.transformClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:262)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.init(WCBufferedContext.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCBufferedContext.getGraphics(WCBufferedContext.java:47)
```

Image of whats happening can be found in my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247703/javafx-webview-rendering-graphical-glitches At the time i have not recieved this error just glitches alone.Now it lead me to this.

That graphical glitch alone doesnt throw exception bud after some changes (goto page google.com -> sector.sk -> facebook.com etc stackoverflow is thrown.I can change up to 1/2 websites and its thrown application then stops responding.)

-Xss  is default now.
As far as i know im using latest `javafx and java 8 u20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the SystemProperty glass.lens.stackSize to set the stack 
size of the JavaFX ApplicationThread. 
It was implemented as part of https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36811.

This might change to glass.monocle.stackSize once we switch to monocle 
though.

You can probably set the property in the generated android project either 
- in the AndroidManifest.xml under Jvm arguments (add 
|-Dglass.lens.stackSize=128000) 
or 
- in assets/javafx.platform.properties (add the line 
android.glass.lens.stackSize=128000)

Haven't tried it yet, but this should increase the stackSize to 128KB, 
which should be more than enough even for very complex applications.

Please tell us, if it worked for you.

====
This came from Stefan Fuchs

Comment: After using parameter -Dglass.lens.stackSize=128000 in VM options ,error went away bud i still struggle with glitching of grpahics in webviews.That have to be something else thats causing it bud i have no way of tracking it cause there aint any errors thrown.